# Google SignIn CocoaPods deprecated

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, google-signin

How to implement Google SignIn in iOS app as now Google pod is deprecated?

Using the deprecated pod is giving 
: Framework not found GoogleAppUtilities

Answer (score 21):

The pod install is indeed 'GoogleSignIn' . However this also means adjusting the bridging header to

```
#import <GoogleSignin/GoogleSignIn.h>
```

And instead of using :

```
GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)
```

You need to use :

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = kClientID
```

And replace kClientID with your client id (You can/need to remove some other lines also regarding the &configureError).

You can find the info here : [Google Sign-In](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in?ver=swift)

The Pod install now follows the manually install method mentioned in the blue notes.

Comment: Where did you find the information about `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = kClientID`?

Comment: You need to register your app for signin at google to get a client id. If it is the source for the code you looking for than check the Google Sign-in link Step 3, the blue block.

Comment: I meant about to use 'GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = kClientID' instead of 'GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)'. The guide tells us to use it only if you add the SDK manually.

Comment: Exactly, the pod version now follows the manual install. Don't know when the google guide gets updated though.

Answer (score 9):

New pod location is:-

```
 pod 'GoogleSignIn'
```

Comment: I did that, Pod installed successfully. But in my bridging header file I have `#import <GoogleSignIn.h>`. It is giving me error that GoogleSignIn.h not found.
Can you please help me in this...
As google documentation is still having old Google pod documentation

Comment: I did that too, but then the build fails with `GGLContext` not found. Thoughts?

Comment: You might want to recheck https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/ because you don't need GGLContext line anymore...

Comment: @AbhigyanSingh , try this <GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignIn.h>